# angular 2 - primeng dataTable add filter for date field, with date range

Tags: angular, momentjs, primeng, primeng-datatable

Suppose I have this data table

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="list" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selection"  [rows]="2"[paginator]="true" >
       <p-column selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
       <p-column field="startDate" header="description" [filter]="true"></p-column>
```

now i want to have a filter which can filter the dates based on 'Last 1 day', 'Last 30 day' and so on

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `startDate` field is JS Date object (it also could be timestamp integer). FIlter's resolution is a day (1 day, 30 days, etc...).

1. Create additional hidden field which will hold day representation for the given `startDate` field value, I called it `dateFilter`. For example if `startDate` is 'Sun Sep 17 2017 00:57:08 GMT+0300 (IDT)', then `dateFilter` will be '2017-09-17':

   ```
   <p-column field="dateFilter" header="Filter" hidden="true"></p-column>
   ```
2. Create HTML filter on `startDate` field using prime ng dropdown:

   ```
   <p-column field="startDate" 
             header="Date" 
             [style]="{'overflow':'visible'}" 
             [sortable]="true">
     <ng-template let-col let-car="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
       <span>{{car[col.field] | date : 'dd-MM-y'}}</span>
     </ng-template>

     <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
       <p-dropdown [options]="filters" 
                   [style]="{'width':'100%'}" 
                   (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, 'dateFilter', 'in')" 
                   styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-dropdown>
     </ng-template>
   </p-column>
   ```

   filters object holds arrays of day representations, for example, if today is '2017-09-17', then filter for last 3 days should look like:

   ```
   [
     '2017-09-17',
     '2017-09-16',
     '2017-09-15'
   ]
   ```

   in my example I have filters for 1, 7 and 20 days:

   ```
   this.filters = [];
   this.filters.push({label: 'All days', value: null});
   this.filters.push({label: 'Last 1 day', value: [this.createFilterDate(currTime)]});
   this.filters.push({label: 'Last 7 days', value: Array(...new Array(7)).map((item, index) => this.createFilterDate(currTime - index * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))});
   this.filters.push({label: 'Last 20 days', value: Array(...new Array(20)).map((item, index) => this.createFilterDate(currTime - index * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))});

   createFilterDate(time) {
     return this.datePipe.transform(new Date(time), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
   }
   ```

filtering is triggered by dropdown change event:

```
(onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, 'dateFilter', 'in')"
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ozZJ21SeNFVA16ng4NRl?p=preview

Comment: what is this field currTime, you haven't mentioned this?

Comment: please see my plunker which I created for you. `currTime` is current apoche time: `const currTime = new Date().getTime();`